# Generate a Static Unique ID for every Computer without storing it locally in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I want to generate a unique id for every computer and it should remain static every time the id is generated which means we dont need to store it in local storage because most of our user disable local storage. So is it possible? I tried to find the way to get mac address of user in actionscript so i can make a unique id from it but i think it's not possible in pure actionscript and flash player.

Any idea how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't do this unless creating an AIR application. (and using class NetworkInfo - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetworkInfo.html)

However, no matter what security measure you create, the user can always fool your system. Anything generated by client machine can always be faked on client machine... CPU/MB serial, sure, just make a hook that returns a random serial every time program asks for it. Or just change the code of the SWF that exists on client machine to generate a "valid" number that it sends to the server.

You should just make it hard enough for a standard user to fool your system. I would suggest username/password combined with IP-address and make sure that only one user-session can be active at same time, and that the same IP can only have one session.